# Not able to run ionic app in my device to debug application

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Iam trying to run the ionic app in my device for logging errors . I am using the following command

```
 ionic cordova run android -l -c -s --debug
```

The app is installing in my device but its showing ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and the application is closing.

[image]

Can some one give solution to this issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Livereload the phone and the development machine (dm) have to be on the same network and the mentioned Port has to be reachable (no Firewall on dm, etc.)

Your phone Shows 4g as Network. Ist has to be in your wifi